# in a SMB environment <or> in an SMB environment

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, vowels

SMB stands for small to midsize business. If I was using 'SMB' on my resume, what would be more appropriate to use before 'SMB'.

1. in a SMB environment

or

2. in an SMB environment

How do I know how the reader will read it? Some read the letters out loud which would produce the "ess" sound which would require the "an" but someone else who knows what it stands for, (which I hope is everyone) will be expecting the preceding word to be "a".

Comment: No; this isn't a difficult case – if it's not pronounceable as an acronym, people will spell it out. So "an SMB". Very few people will pronounce "SNB" as "small to midsize business". The difficult cases are ones like SNP, where you don't know whether they'll say "snip" or "ess en pee".

Comment: This is a duplicate several times over, but I'm too lazy to look up the reference.  The issue is **how is it pronounced**.  If it's pronounced "ess em bee" then that starts with a vowel sound and you use "an".  If it's pronounced, say, "samb" then that starts with a consonant sound and you use "a".